# How can I implement newly built kernel in ChromiumOS?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, chromium-os

I have been up and down trying to enable a new kernel I built for my Chromium OS, but I'm stuck at figuring out how I can tell the image build to use the new kernel vs the stock 3.14.0 that the build comes with.

I don't know where else to look, or what else to do. The kernel build image.sh script doesn't seem too helpful either, but I could very well be missing something.  Is anyone else out there familiar with this by chance?

Thank you!

Edit: Sites I've looked at are below, just a small handful though of the many I've scoured through:

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-os-dev/PVxdASizNP0/kpdIdozsb8gJ

https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Build-chrome-os-kernel-and-kernel-modules

http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in the event that someone in the future stumbles across this, I never did find a solution to implement the newest upstream kernel. Instead, I found out which kernel the image was using by default (in my case, v3.14), added my drivers (well, selected the modules) and ran the following commands as an amd64-generic build

`~/trunk/src/scripts/./build_packages --board=amd64-generic` # Yes, I know, you can export board = amd64-generic here, too.
`cros_workon --board=amd64-generic start sys-kenel/chromeos-kernel-3_14-9999`
`cd ~/trunk/third_party/kernel/v3.14/`
`./chromeos/scripts/prepareconfig chromiumos-x86_64`
`./chromeos/scripts/kernelconfig editconfig` # Answer the questions here in the menus.
`make mrproper`
`cd ~/trunk/src/scripts/./build_packages --board=amd64-generic`
`cros_workon --board=amd64-generic stop sys-kernel/chromeos-kernel-3_14-9999`
`./build_image --board=amd64-generic --noenable_rootfs_verification`

Comment: Hey Michael how did you add the drivers. I want to add wifi drivers for my laptop but couldn't find anything. Could you please help?